# Property 'idToken' does not exist on type 'CognitoUserSession'

Tags: typescript, aws-amplify

I am trying to destructure `payload` from `idToken` within `userData`.

`userData` is of type `CognitoUserSession`.

```
import { CognitoUser } from "@aws-amplify/auth";
import { CognitoUserSession, CognitoIdToken } from "amazon-cognito-identity-js";

  const userData = await Auth.currentSession().catch(e => console.log(e));
  if (!userData) {
    console.log(`User data : ${userData}`);
    updateUser({} as CognitoUser);
    return;
  }
    const {
    idToken: { payload: CognitoIdToken }
  } : CognitoUserSession = userData;
```

But I get the error that `idToken does not exist on type CognitoUserSession` but in its class it exist.

```
export interface ICognitoUserSessionData {
    IdToken: CognitoIdToken;
    AccessToken: CognitoAccessToken;
    RefreshToken?: CognitoRefreshToken;
}

export class CognitoUserSession {
    constructor(data: ICognitoUserSessionData);

    public getIdToken(): CognitoIdToken;
    public getRefreshToken(): CognitoRefreshToken;
    public getAccessToken(): CognitoAccessToken;
    public isValid(): boolean;
}

export class CognitoAccessToken {
    payload: { [key: string]: any };

    constructor({ AccessToken }: { AccessToken: string });

    public getJwtToken(): string;
    public getExpiration(): number;
    public getIssuedAt(): number;
    public decodePayload(): { [id: string]: any };
}

export class CognitoIdToken {
    payload: { [key: string]: any };

    constructor({ IdToken }: { IdToken: string });

    public getJwtToken(): string;
    public getExpiration(): number;
    public getIssuedAt(): number;
    public decodePayload(): { [id: string]: any };
}
```

Comment: Actually your statement that it exist is wrong. It does not. CognitoUserSession  has no idToken member. It has a getIdToken method but not a idToken member

Comment: @MartinGodzina ah you're right. I will just leave it as ```any``` for the moment and log it to see what gets outputted exactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the AWS team updated the aws-amplify package. If you want to destructure use the old package `aws-amplify`. You are using the new package `@aws-amplify/auth` that now uses the getter function so you can no longer destructure.

try `const { payload } = (await Auth.currentSession()).getIdToken()`